# Magento Configurable Product Pricing

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I need some help with finding out how to work the Configurable Product attributes in Magento. I'm using Magento for a restaurant site and I need to be able to make different sizes of a food item at different prices but I want to keep them using the same product.  So for example it would be like this.

- Small Pizza 8.95
- Medium Pizza 9.95
- Large Pizza 10.95

But instead of having three completely different products, which I believe would complicate things very much so for the consumer, I would like to have one product that would allow the user to choose what size and be able to see what the price of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout these tutorials

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Video tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK6LIBBxepk

Comment: I would like to thank you for your answer @blakcaps They should be useful.

Answer (score 2):

its very simple.Just create a configurable product, and you are done!!!
Go through this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK6LIBBxepk